# how to use rvest to scrape same kind of datapoint but labelled with different id

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

if I want to use rvest to **scrape** a particular datapoint (name, address, phone etc) repeated in different section of this [page](http://www.straitstimes.com/lifestyle/food/full-list-of-michelin-starred-restaurants-for-2017), all start with similar span id, but not exactly the same, such as:

```
docs-internal-guid-049ac94a-f34e-5729-b053-30567fdf050a
docs-internal-guid-765e48e9-f34b-7c88-5d95-042a93fcfda3
```

what's the best approach? to find and copy each id is not viable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
You can use the following script to retrieve all star restaurants:

```
library("rvest")

url_base <- "http://www.straitstimes.com/lifestyle/food/full-list-of-michelin-starred-restaurants-for-2017"
data <- read_html(url_base) %>%
   html_nodes("h3") %>%
   html_text()
```

This also gives you the headers ("ONE MICHELIN STAR", "TWO MICHELIN STARS", "THREE MICHELIN STARS"), bu this might even be helpful.

Background to the script:
Fortunately, all and only the relevant information is within the h3 selector. The script gives you a char vector as output. Of course, you can further elaborate on this with e.g. %>% as.data.frame() or however you want to store / process the data.

------------------- old answer -------------------

Could you maybe provide the url of that particular page? For me it sounds like you have to find the right css-selector (nth-child(x)) you can use in a loop.

Comment: I'm just a bit in a hurry, but as a start you could try looping through the h3:nth-child(7)

library("rvest")

url_test <- "http://www.straitstimes.com/lifestyle/food/full-list-of-michelin-starred-restaurants-for-2017"
test <- read_html(url_test)

data <- test %>%
   html_nodes(".odd > h3:nth-child(7) > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)") %>%
   html_text()

Comment: thanks! this is already a big step forward. till i read up more about css and how nth_child works, may i know what do u mean by looping through nth-child(7), do i replace 7 with other numbers?

Comment: (sry browser crashed): use a for loop "for (i in 1:x) { }" to iterate with "i" through the corresponding child selector (in this case h3:nth-child(**i**)). Sometimes it is not necessary to loop, but to provide one certain selector that contains all relevant information, but (based on my little experience) it's easier to retrieve the child oeprators using the "Inspect element" function of your browser: right click on Element -> Inspect element -> in the inspector at bottom choose the highlighted line (or another one around that might fit better) and right click -> copy -> CSS selector

Comment: really appreciate your patient guidance. i'll learn more abt nth-child.